# Как правильно работать с RestController?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller

Сразу извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, но:

У меня есть `@Controller` который я переделываю `@RestController` + js.

Вот один из методов:

```
@GetMapping
    public ModelAndView showAll() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/departments");
        List<DepartmentDto> departmentDtos = departmentService.findAll();

        if (departmentDtos.isEmpty()) {
            mav.setViewName("redirect:/api/departments/new");
        } else {
            mav.addObject("departmentDtos", departmentDtos);
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

Насколько я понимаю, контроллер должен иметь следующий вид:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentDto>> showAll() {
    List<DepartmentDto> departmentDtos = departmentService.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(departmentDtos, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

На JS я возвращаю этот объект и дальше делаю свою логику. *Если список пустой - перенаправляю на другую стр и т.д.* Это верно?

Доп вопросы:

- Методы `RestController` возвращают только один объект? Если нет -
  как вернуть 2 и более (к примеру два списка)? (вариант c ModelAndView считаю некорректным)
- Если использовать `RestController` - всю логику redirect и forward -
  лучше оставить на js?
- Возможно ли вернуть View (jsp/html etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Основной вопрос**
Верно, но лучше использовать обёртку и в контроллере возвращать что-то вроде следующего:

```
public class Response {

    private List<DepartamentsDto> departamentsDtos;

    public List<DepartamentsDto> getDepartamentsDtos() {
        return departamentsDtos;
    }

    public void setDepartamentsDtos(List<DepartamentsDto> departamentsDtos) {
        this.departamentsDtos = departamentsDtos;
    }
    
}
```

`ResponseEntity` удобен, когда вам нужно заносить в ответ какие то кастомные заголовки или переопределять существующие. Если использовать его просто так, то когда-нибудь с Вас спросят смысл этого действия :)

**Первый доп. вопрос**

Опять же, если использовать обёртку то можно возвращать хоть миллиард полей:

```
public class Response {
    
    private List<DepartamentsDto> departamentsDtos;
    private List<Departaments1Dto> departaments1Dtos;
    private List<Departaments2Dto> departaments2Dtos;
    private List<Departaments3Dto> departaments3Dtos;
    
    private String name;
    private String age;
    
    // ... Getters and setters
    
}
```

Endpoint будет выглядеть так:

```
@GetMapping("/response")
public Response getResponse() {
    // logic
}
```

**Второй доп. вопрос**

Насчёт редиректов можете почитать тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638150/best-approach-to-redirect-an-url-using-rest

**Третий доп. вопрос**

Можете попробовать вот так ::

```
@GetMapping("/main")
public String getMain() {
    return "view.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. RestController. Может вернуть что в голову взбредет. Файл, объект, да хоть зелёного гнома.

```
@GetMapping("/manual")
void manual(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("Custom-Header", "foo");
    response.setStatus(200);
    response.getWriter().println("Hello World!");
}
```

Хочешь хоть напрямую сокет открывай и долби в него разную, ересь.

- https://www.techtudes.in/stream-video-using-spring-boot-chunk-by-chunk-over-http/

2. Можно, но не нужно. Для этого есть обычный контроллер, создай обычный контроллер и там уже работай с вьюшками. Это избавит тебя от лишнего геморроя с ручной инициализацией ModelAndView